# how to Highlight cells value based on another cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that highlighted & colors the empty cells in a specific column (AE), but I need to clear this color-highlighted based on a result that exists in the column (AD)

If AD column, cells value = "SPLICE" clear color, If Empty the color should exist, below picture explains more.
I use the code below

```
Sub EmptyTerminalTO()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Wire List").Activate
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set myRange = Range("AD2", Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each myCell In myRange '
    c = c + 1
    If (myCell) = "" Then
        myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 87, 87)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next myCell

Rapport8 = i

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using conditional formatting for such task if I may ask?

Comment: I'm still a beginner I try to learn something every day

Comment: Well, would it be sufficient to select column AE:AE and use conditional formatting with the custom foruma rule: `=AND(ROW()>1,$AD1<>"SPLICE")`?

Comment: Thanks a Lot, @JvdV for your help, and I'm so sorry because I still didn't know how to achieve that , If can help me please it's will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: I believe the steps are self-explanatory. 1) Select column `AE:AE`, then 2) open 'Conditional formatting' (under the 'Home' tab). 3) Select 'New Rule' and choose to use a formula. 4) Use the formula from the previous comment and pick whatever formatting before accepting the rule.

Comment: I get it bro, But my macro didn't do only this I have a lot of modules and search in multiple sheets, still only this issue, maybe I think my question has not been understood correctly. anyway thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

try using offset as per code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmptyTerminalTO()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Wire List").Activate
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long, Rapport8 As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set myRange = Range("AD2", Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each myCell In myRange '
    c = c + 1
    If myCell <> "SPLICE" & myCell.Offset(0, 1)="" Then
        myCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 87, 87)
    Else
        myCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    i = i + 1
    End If
Next myCell

Rapport8 = i

 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thnx a lot @NoobVB like always, But this code highlight all the column AD except the splices, in the example I shared I try to highlight "Empty" cells in column "AE" except Splice mentioned in column "AD"

Comment: just adjust it to your needs as for example `If myCell <> "SPLICE" & myCell.Offset(0, 1)="" Then`

Comment: Thanks a Lot, @NoobVB, like always  you are a very helpful person I really appreciate that